# Reverse proxy apache and nginx

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx

This is my nginx config:

```
server {
    listen 33333;
    server_name domain.com www.domain.com;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/domain.com_access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/domain.com_error.log;

    location / {
        uwsgi_pass  unix:///tmp/domain.com.sock;
        include     uwsgi_params;
    }

    location /media/  {
        alias /home/pw/projects/runenv/webr/webr/media/;
    }

    location  /static/ {
        alias  /home/pw/projects/runenv/webr/webr/static/;
    }
}
```

I have nginx and apache on the same server. How to run this site like reverse proxy on apache?

Now my website work only on domain.com:33333 I need run this on 80 port.

How to configure apache for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be something like

```
<VirtualHost x.x.x.x:80>
   ProxyPreserveHost On
   ProxyRequests Off

   ProxyPass / http://x.x.x.x:33333/
   ProxyPassReverse / http://x.x.x.x:33333/
   ...
</VirtualHost>
```

You can get more info at http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html

Comment: Thanks. I still have on domain.com - `It works!

This is the default web page for this server.

The web server software is running but no content has been added, yet.` domain.com:33333 work correctly

Comment: either use name based virtual hosting, or remove the config pointing to docroot, since apache will use the first config it finds as the default).  so assuming you have name based virtual hosting setup. adding servername domain.com to the above *should* make it work.

Comment: @Doon: https://dpaste.de/wCoww/ Still does not work :(

Comment: there is some other host in your apache config that is overriding this config, you'll need to find it.  But do you actually need to run apache? why not just let nginx listen on port 80?

Comment: @Doon: yes, I need apache also. I don't see another host to overwrite this apache configuration

Comment: do you have a `NameVirtualHost *:80` in your apache config?

Comment: @Doon: Yes, I have

Comment: I at a loss, it should work as is, normally when it doesn't there is something else taking precedence.

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? What in the log files apache/nginx?

Comment: @ALex_hha: If I run domain.com I have only `It works! This is the default web page for this server. The web server software is running but no content has been added, yet.` If I run domain.com:33333 I have my website. On domain.com should be website from nginx

Comment: I have tested on test machine with static html page and all works fine.